# Route particular requests to different host with Rails 3 while preserving path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

We're on Rails 3.2.12.

We would like to route all requests under directory X to a different host while preserving the path, essentially just swapping out the host information. This is what we're doing now, but we're wondering what the proper way is since this seems to URL encode part of the path.

```
match '/X/*path' => redirect( 'http://newhost.com/X/%{path}', :status => 302 )
```

What's a clean way to reroute these types of requests to a different host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what wound up working for us:

```
match '/X/*path' => redirect( host: 'newhost.com', port: 80, :status => 302 )
```